# 'es' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10

when I run a python script from powershell on windows 10, the script runs successfully but at the end it outputs the following even though I have never typed any such command like `es`

```
'es' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

And once this error message is shown I also find an empty file being generated by the following name(it has no extension):

```
 datetime(2021
```

The error is intermittent , happens 20% of the times for running the same python script from same directory from same powershell.

I am running `python myfile.py`

Here is the code in `myfile.py`

```
from __future__ import print_function
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from device_facade_v2 import DeviceFacade
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from pathlib import Path
from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient
import colorama
import pprint as pp
import requests
import socket

global device_id

    
filepath = str(Path(__file__).resolve())
if "/" in filepath:
    pathsplit = filepath.split("/")
else:
    pathsplit = filepath.split("\\")

root = "/".join(pathsplit[:-1])

adb_host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())


def get_adb_devices():
    client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
    devices = client.devices()

    adb_device_list = []
    for device in devices:
        try:
            print()
            print("DEVICE:" + device.serial)
            prop = device.shell("getprop")
            proplines = prop.split("\n")
            for propline in proplines:
                if "[ro.product.board]" in propline:
                    # print(propline)
                    board = (
                        propline.split(":")[1].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").strip()
                    )
                if "[ro.product.brand]" in propline:
                    # print(propline)
                    brand = (
                        propline.split(":")[1].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").strip()
                    )
                if "[ro.product.model]" in propline:
                    print(propline)
                    model = (
                        propline.split(":")[1].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").strip()
                    )

            try:
                socket.inet_aton(device.serial.split(":")[0])
                print(device.serial.split(":")[0])
                adb_device_list.append(
                    {
                        "serial": device.serial,
                        "ip_address": device.serial.split(":")[0],
                        "board": board,
                        "brand": brand,
                        "model": model,
                    }
                )
                continue
            except socket.error:
                pass

            ip_address_blob = device.shell("ip addr")
            ip_address_splits = ip_address_blob.split(" ")
            ip_address_splits_cleaned = []
            for comp in ip_address_splits:
                if "192.168." not in comp:
                    continue
                ip_address_splits_cleaned.append(comp)
            print(ip_address_splits_cleaned)

            for comp in ip_address_splits:
                if len(comp) < 11 or len(comp) > 18:
                    continue
                if "192.168." not in comp:
                    continue
                if "192.168.0.255" in comp:
                    continue
                if "192.168.68.255" in comp:
                    continue
                try:
                    socket.inet_aton(comp)
                    adb_device_list.append(
                        {
                            "serial": device.serial,
                            "ip_address": comp,
                            "board": board,
                            "brand": brand,
                            "model": model,
                        }
                    )
                    # print(comp.split("/")[0])
                except socket.error:
                    pass
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    return adb_device_list


if __name__ == "__main__":

    connected_devices = get_adb_devices()
    print("\n\nconnected_devices(raw):")
    pp.pprint(connected_devices)

    print("\n\nconnected_devices(unsorted):")
    for connected_device in connected_devices:
        connected_device["port"] = ""
        try:
            connected_device["port"] = connected_device["serial"].split(":")[1]
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        print(connected_device["serial"], connected_device["model"])

    connected_devices = sorted(connected_devices, key=lambda k: k["port"])

    print("\n\n {} connected_devices(sorted):".format(len(connected_devices)))
    for connected_device in connected_devices:
        print(connected_device["serial"], connected_device["model"])
```

**Added code as per the request even though I dont think code is relevant here. IT IS HAPPENING WITH ALL MY PYTHON FILES IRRESPECTIVE OF WHAT CODE IS IN THAT FILE.**

And here is the screenhot of the output on powershell:
(Check the last line for the error message, ie after showing all the successful outputs)
https://snipboard.io/RhNanP.jpg

Comment: The error message is emitted by `cmd.exe`, not by PowerShell. If it happens with all your Python files, perhaps the problem is in your PowerShell prompt function. (Temporarily) reset it with `$function:prompt = $null`, which defaults to just `PS>` as the prompt string, and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: where should I type `$function:prompt = $null`, on powershell before running the script ? or put it in `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` ?

Comment: well added it in `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 ` unfortunately it didn't solve the isssue

Answer (score 0):

Running the following via an elevated command prompt seems to have solved the issue.

```
cd C:\WINDOWS\system32
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

For details of windows repair check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e)